# Switch two or more digital outputs of ESP8266 at the same time

Tags: esp8266, pins, port-mapping

I'd like to control some digital ICs with a ESP8266-12.

1. How can I switch 2 pins to HIGH in the same moment?
2. How can I switch one to LOW and the other to HIGH in the same moment?
3. Is it possible with every port or only with grouped ports and how are the groups?

Comment: Maybe have a look in [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/44531/arduino-esp8266-direct-fast-control-of-the-digital-pins) direction

Answer (score 1):

See the datasheet: [esp8266-technical_reference_en](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp8266-technical_reference_en.pdf)

Paragraph 2.2.2 shows how to use the output registers.

With the registers GPIO_OUT, GPIO_OUT_W1TS and GPIO_OUT_W1TC you can set or clear multiple GPIOs.